# Implementing an SSO solution for a node.js application

Tags: node.js, single-sign-on, wso2-identity-server

we would like to develop a new node.js based application using some SSO technology.
More applications will join then after using the same SSO infrastructure and logic.
We do not have specific requirements on the SSO itself, but it need to authenticate users

- via a local DB (managing user name and passwords)
- via our enterprise AD
- via some external/federated SSO (I guess via SAML or so)

Also if it would support XACML it would be great. 
I believe one of the most complete solutions on the market is the WSO2 Identity Server... but we would be open for others too.

The main question though is simply: 
Is it possible to have such a solution in node.js? 
Or do we need to shield node.js behind some (Apache) server to get SSO?
What would be the best approach?
Any inputs would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used [azure active directory](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/active-directory/) in my node.js projects for authentication, this might work as you are using active directory. Here is a [sample](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/AzureAD-Node-Sample/).